# power a 5V source from an android headphone

Tags: microphone, 5v

I need an android headphone to turn off and on a 5V source
The android heafphone supplies an AC voltage (maybe 0.6V) at a frequency of my choice.
I want this to open/close the 5V supply (from another battery) such that when I play a note down the headphone, the 5V device is powered.

Alternatively, what is the simplest circuit that will allow my headphone to power an LED and have that LED always on?  I can then use the light from the led into my optoelectronic switch to control the 5V

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions with a lower-cost BOM and more parts (10 cents or so is possible), but a very easy approach would be to use an [LM567](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm567c.pdf) tone detector chip.

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm567c.pdf]

Obviously you'd use a lower frequency than 100kHz in the above example, maybe 1kHz, and you'd want the bandwidth to be fairly wide, maybe 10%, to account for component tolerances.

This would have the advantage that it would not easily be triggered by random audio at the input.

Comment: that looks great.  where does the 5V come out when it sees the correct input signal? how do i change frequency and does it use much power when a) signal and b) no signal?

Comment: It's all in the datasheet linked above. Pin 8 is an open-collector output and is pulled low upon detection (energizing RL). Frequency and BW calculations are in the datasheet. It typically draws 6 or 11mA from the 5V rail.